# Is any way to offline install Devtoolset-3 on CentOS 6.8?

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, yum, devtoolset

The steps to install `Devtoolset-3` at CentOS by yum are [here](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-3/).

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install devtoolset-3
scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

But I do not have the network access ability at my CentOS 6.8 server. (I can access network at other PC.)
Is there any `Devtoolset-3` installer to be downloaded for offline installation?

I would like to upgrade `binutils` by installing `Devtoolset-3`. Is there any other way to upgrade `binutils` if I have no connection?